# How would you refactor this polymorphic design in order to make it more flexible when adding new implementations?

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, polymorphism

I have a class that has many virtual functions that allows you to obtain references to interfaces. Clients using my API can implement my interfaces, then implement my top-level interface IMyInterface using their implementations.

My code then acts on their polymorphic IMyInterface implementation.

Here's some example code (not the real code, but you get the idea):

```
class MyImplementation : public IMyInterface
{

    public:

        virtual Interface1& get1()
        {
            return impl1
        }

        virtual Interface2& get2()
        {
            return impl2;
        }

        // etc...

    public:

        Impl1 impl1;

        Impl2 impl2;

        // etc...


};
```

I thought this design seemed really nice, but one day I wanted to change one of the implementations, but only one. In that case I had to rewrite the entire class and copy a lot of code.

There are actually 6 Impl objects, so I'd have to rewrite a class that has the exact same 5 Impl objects, but with one different.

Another problem is that people rely on this API design, so I need to keep the basics of it.

Is there a way to modify the design to make it more flexible, while still maintaining this API?

Comment: Maybe more suited for CodeReview or Programmers?

Comment: Why do you have to "rewrite the entire class and copy a lot of code" shown here as a result changing something about "Impl2", for example?

Comment: @J... code review requires working code, not `etc...` "implementations."

Comment: I don't have to literally rewrite the entire class. I would just copy all the code and change "Impl2" to "Impl8" or something.

I just se a problem coming in the future. I need to copy the code each time I want to change a single implementatoin.

Comment: Does Impl8 inherit Interface2? Wait, why are those impl instances public?

Comment: @J... when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Answer (score 1):

**What I understand from your question:**

If I understand correctly, you are wording with classes that are more or less and assembly of basic components, and you want to be able to exchange components with a minimum of coding.

**Alternative 1: dynamic assembly**

Why not opt them for a dynamic assembly at construction:

```
class MyBase : public IMyInterface
{
public:
   Interface1& get1()  { return *pimpl1; }
   Interface2& get2()  { return *pimpl2; }
   //...
   Interfacen& getn()  { return *pimpln; }

protected:
   MyBase (unique_ptr<Interface1> p1, 
             unique_ptr<Interface2> p2, 
             /*...*/ 
             unique_ptr<Interfacen> pn) : // constructor assembles parts
                   pimpl1(move(p1)),pimpl2(move(p2)),/*...*/pimpln(move(pn)) {}
private:
   unique_ptr<Interface1> pimpl1;  // implemented with unique ptr for greater safety
   unique_ptr<Interface2> pimpl2;  
   //...
   unique_ptr<Interfacen> pimpln;
};
```

With such a logic, your derived classes would look like:

```
class MyImplementationX : public MyBase {
public: 
   MyImplementationX() : MyBase(make_unique<Impl1>(), make_unique<Impl2>(), /*...*/ make_unique<Impln>()) {}
}; 

class MyImplementationY : public MyBase {
public: 
   MyImplementationX() : MyBase(make_unique<Impl1>(), make_unique<Impl2b>(), /*...*/ make_unique<Impln>()) {}
};
```

**Alternative 2: compile-time assembly**

You could get rid of the runtime assembly, the additional allocations and the smart pointers, by using templates:

```
template <class I1, class I2, /*...*/ class IN, 
          class M1, class M2, /*...*/ class M3>
class MyBase {
public: 
     I1& get1() { return m1; }
     I2& get2() { return m2; }
     ...
private: 
     M1 m1; 
     M2 m2;
     ...
};
```

By the way, there's an excellent book about this kind of design: "*Modern C++ design*" by A.Alexandrescu, in which the author promotes a "[policy based design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Policy-based_design)" (the policies being there a strategy pattern implemented with templates).